# Ansible task to run script on localhost

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a script on my Ansible localhost. What I have now is:

```
    - name: "Cherrytree - execute build.sh"
      ansible.builtin.shell: "./build.sh"
      args:
        chdir: /opt/Build/cherrytree
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
ERROR! this task 'ansible.builtin.shell' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: win_shell, import_tasks, add_host, meta, script, include_tasks, import_role, shell, win_command, raw, group_by, include_vars, include_role.
```

I'm just trying to run a script that will install cherrytree using Ansible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running an old version of ansible with the new style namespaced modules; since `shell:` still works fine both ways, you'll be better off using the old style `shell:` since it will work for the foreseeable future. Pedantically, you don't need `shell:` for that, either, since you're not using any "shell" features, the `command:` task is designed for things one can `exec`

Comment: I just did an upgrade to Ansible and changed the task to the below and it's still not working. 
  - name: "Cherrytree - execute build.sh"
      ansible.builtin.command: /opt/Build/cherrytree/build.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *chdir* argument of shell module, instead of trying to pass it with args.

```
- name: "Cherrytree - execute build.sh"
  ansible.builtin.shell: 
     cmd: "./build.sh"
     chdir: /opt/Build/cherrytree
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem, too, but [the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#examples) show the syntax used by OP, which is why I strongly suspect it's the `ansible.bulitin.` part that's causing them trouble

Comment: Yes that's more likely. I originally wanted to post as comment but I have no rep points yet ..